# redirect to same page with header("Location: " . $MyPage); not working

Tags: php, redirect, parameters, header, uri

My plugin (admin side pages) edits , updates etc in place, using params on the url..i.e.

http://www.sandwichbaron.com/dev/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-page-handle&Action=Edit&recId=1

and once I have done edited and updated my db table, 
I use

```
header("Location: " . $MyPage);   
 $MyPage = http://www.sandwichbaron.com/dev/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-page-handle
```

i.e.....no params

and
it shows in the browser url address bar **with the params still in place.????** 
So I ( and the client) have to manually refresh the page, to see the changes.

I'm reading about weird htaccess files etc, but I am stuck..clueless...exasperated
Can someone please help out.

Comment: **"no params"** what ?? What are you asking ? Your URL still have parameter ie **page=....** !

Comment: @phazorRise is absolutely right - is the content of the $MyPage variable in your comment a typo? If so, and you want it to redirect to admin.php with no variables, it sounds like the headers have already been sent and the redirect is not taking effect.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the variable $MyPage before inserting it into the header, and wrap it in quotes. Also you should always use `exit()` after a redirect call to `header()`:

```
$MyPage = "http://www.sandwichbaron.com/dev/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-page-handle";
header("Location: " . $MyPage);   
exit();
```

Comment: ok, typo,...I do set $MyPage = "yad yada" first, then call header("location: " . $MyPage);

Comment: Nope: still retains the parameters in the url even after I explicitly force it to redirect to the url beneath.                 I have the following                                       header("Status: 301"); header('Location: http://www.sandwichbaron.com/dev/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-submenu-handle');                                                           exit();

Comment: The first call to [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is wrong, look at the documentation. 1. argument: header, 2. replace?, 3. response code (status). So you need `header("Location: ...", true, 301);`